# Printf function arguments

Tags: c

`printf()` accepts variable number of arguments (sometimes 2 arguments, sometimes 3 arguments,etc.) and therefore this statement works

```
printf ("%d %d %d",i,j);
```

what does this mean?

Comment: It means that you should learn about *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Look into ellipsis, variadic function arguments and `<stdarg.h>`

Answer (score 1):

`printf()` will read some variable from the stack happens to be in the place of that missing `%d`. On my computer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i = 1, j = 2;

  printf("%d %d %d", i, j);
  return 0;
}
```

will prints:

```
1 2 4201256
```

This number `4201256` can be explained by viewing the stack content:

```
...
0022FF00  00403064  .rdata:aDDD
0022FF04  00000001                          ; 1
0022FF08  00000002                          ; 2
0022FF0C  00401B28  sub_401AE0+48           ; 0x00401B28 = 4201256 (third %d)
0022FF10  00401A60  sub_401650:loc_401A60
...
```

You can get any number depending on the architecture, compiler, optimization ..etc.

Read about [stack frame/call stack/activation record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).